# How to display the differences comparing two images?

Tags: c#, winforms

if the two images are not the same i want to display the different pixels between the two images in a pictureBox1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ImageComparison
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string fname1, fname2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Images";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Images|*.jpg; *.bmp; *.png";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString() != "")
            {
                fname1 = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog2.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog2.Title = "Images";
            openFileDialog2.Filter = "All Images|*.jpg; *.bmp; *.png";
            openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
            if (openFileDialog2.FileName.ToString() != "")
            {
                fname2 = openFileDialog2.FileName.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            int count1 = 0,count2 = 0;
            bool flag = true;
            string img1_ref, img2_ref;
            Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(fname1);
            Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap(fname2);
            progressBar1.Maximum = img1.Width;
            if (img1.Width == img2.Width && img1.Height == img2.Height)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < img1.Width; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < img1.Height; j++)
                    {
                        img1_ref = img1.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
                        img2_ref = img2.GetPixel(i, j).ToString();
                        if (img1_ref != img2_ref)
                        {
                            count2++;
                            flag = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        count1++;
                    }
                    progressBar1.Value++;
                }
                if (flag == false)
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Images are not same , " + count2 + " wrong pixels found");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show(" Images are same , " + count1 + " same pixels found and " + count2 + " wrong pixels found");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("can not compare this images");
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

either when count2 is increasing line 70 then to display pixel by pixel until the end of the operation or in the end of the operation to display all the pixels at once. the goal is to display the different pixels in the pictureBox1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the condition, where you increment the count2 change the not equal pixel of the first image to some color with `img1.SetPixel(i, j, newColor);` and in the end of your check display the img1 in the picture box.